# SHA1CryptoServiceProvider changed in .NET 4

Tags: cryptography, .net-4.0, sha1

I am currently trying to upgrade a project of mine from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0

Everything was going really well, all code compiled, all tests passed.
Then I hit a problem deploying to my staging environment.
Suddenly my logins were no longer working.

It seems my SHA1 hashed passwords are being hashed differently in .NET 4.

I am using the SHA1CryptoServiceProvider:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvidercryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
```

To test I created a new Visual Studio project with 2 console applications.
The first targeted at .NET Framework 3.5 and the second at 4.0.
I ran exactly the same hashing code in both and different results were produced.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?
I obviously cannot go update all of my users passwords considering I do not know what they are.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CODE SAMPLE

```
public static class SHA1Hash
{

    public static string Hash(string stringToHash)
    {
        return (Hash(stringToHash, Encoding.Default));
    }

    public static string Hash(string stringToHash, Encoding enc)
    {
        byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(stringToHash + stringToHash.Reverse());
        var cryptoTransformSHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        string hash = BitConverter.ToString(cryptoTransformSHA1.ComputeHash(buffer));
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Login fails after upgrade to ASP.net 4.0 from 3.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739196/login-fails-after-upgrade-to-asp-net-4-0-from-3-5) -- solution included

Comment: unfortunately this is not the same case. This is regarding FormsAuthenticationCookies and ViewState and is only a problem "if you run mixed ASP.NET 2.0/ASP.NET 4".

But DANG I thought it was my solution

Comment: Can you clear up the AsymetricHash/Hash confusion? Just to be safe.

Comment: Henk, you've solved my problem here. String.Reverse is a Linq function which reverses a string. It however returns a IEnumerable<char>. Trying to call "StringValue".Reverse().ToString() simply returns the type name. As these were differen't type names in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0, I was getting different hashed values.

Sorry .NET 4.0, you have done well all along.
Thanks all for the help

Comment: Henk, please can you place an answer pointing out the stringToHash.Reverse being suspect so i can mark that as the solution. you did have a comment pointing this out which i think you have removed. thanks

Comment: urgh. you should check your user database to make sure you didn't screw that up too :D everyone might have the same hash... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments led me onto finding the bug in my code.
When creating my byte array to be hashed, I was trying to append the string with a reversed version of itself.

E.g. given "password" to hash I would actually hash "passworddrowssap"

However my code has a slight bug in it:

```
byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(stringToHash + stringToHash.Reverse());
```

.Reverse() is a Linq extension method that can reverse a string.
However it doesn't return a string, it returns:

```
IEnumerable<Char>
```

Calling .ToString() on this type actually returns:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__99`1[System.Char]

Doing the same thing in .NET 4.0 returns

> System.Linq.Enumerable+d__a0`1[System.Char]

Hence my passwords were being hashed differently.
What I should have done to create by byte array was:

```
byte[] buffer = enc.GetBytes(stringToHash + new String(stringToHash.Reverse().ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be character encoding problem. Ensure that the string being hashed is in the encoding [utf8, ansi etc] you expect (and if it is, ensure that the old environment is too.)

-Oisin

Comment: I've been using Encoding.Default.  
I tried specifying an Encoding and none of the following worked:

Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF32, Encoding.UTF7, Encoding.UTF8

Comment: hashing works at the byte stream level - I'm not sure if you understand me. You are specifying encoding where? All that matters is that both systems are verified to be feeding the same _bytes_ to the sha1 class.

Comment: please see the code sample which is the method I call.
Both sites are running on exactly the same server so I'm not sure where the encoding would be changing. How can I verify that both systems are feeding the same bytes to the sha1 class?
as per my above code sample, can I just check buffer.Length ?

Comment: Encoding.Default may be different on each system (while your users hashes are obviously invariable.) Verify the default encoding with a simple console app (or use powershell) on each system. My default encoding is windows-1252; someone else's may differ.

Comment: (and btw, if the hash is different - you must assume the byte streams are different. sha1 algorithm didn't change between frameworks)