# Login Not Working with Custom Profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, webforms, asp.net-profiles, asp.net-4.5

This is a Web Forms Application Project (WAP). I am programmatically creating a user with [custom profile](http://leedumond.com/blog/asp-net-profiles-in-web-application-projects/) properties and can see the user data being persisted in the Users table but not in the aspnet_membership or Memberships tables. After creating a new user with a custom register form, the login fails. **Can anyone suggest a troubleshooting checklist?**

```
MembershipCreateStatus status = MembershipCreateStatus.Success;
MembershipUser newUser 
    = Membership.CreateUser(userNameTxt.Text.Trim(), passwordTxt.Text, 
        emailTxt.Text, questionTxt.Text, answerTxt.Text, true, out status);
Roles.AddUserToRole(userNameTxt.Text.Trim(), "Member");

// Gather and save Profile info
CustomProfile profile = CustomProfile.GetProfile(userNameTxt.Text.Trim());
profile.Personal.Email = emailTxt.Text.Trim();
profile.Personal.FirstName = firstNameTxt.Text.Trim();
profile.Personal.LastName = lastNameTxt.Text.Trim();
profile.Save();
```

**Error Message:** Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.

**What's happening:** CreateUser is returning null

```
      <providers>
          <remove name="DefaultMembershipProvider"/>
          <add 
              name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
              type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" 
              enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
              enablePasswordReset="true" 
              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" 
              requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
              minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
              minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
              passwordAttemptWindow="1000" 
              passwordFormat="Hashed"
              applicationName="/" />
      </providers>

<remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
      connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYDB;Data Source=WIN2K8;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name="MYDBConn" />
      <add name="MYDBConn" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MYDB;Data Source=WIN2K8;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently in .NET 4, the default Hash Algorithm used is HMACSHA256 and not SHA1 as it used to be in previous Framework versions. I found the solution here:

[ASP.NET Membership - User Password storage](http://forums.softfluent.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=233)

[Login fails after upgrade to ASP.net 4.0 from 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739196/login-fails-after-upgrade-to-asp-net-4-0-from-3-5)

I just tweaked my config file for SHA1 as follows:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA1">
    ...
</membership>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before creating a user from your code, please make sure you can create a user using [ASP.Net Configuration](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership).

[image]

Here are some suggestions ["Your Login Attempt was not Successful. Please Try Again." - ASP.NET Login Control.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27682/Your-Login-Attempt-was-not-Successful-Please-Try)

Comment: I can create a user with config tool but since I'm using profiles it has to be a custom form. Will try suggestions in the link you posted :)

Comment: FYI, in VS2012 the tool is reached with the Project drop down. The icon is no longer where it used to be...

Comment: I'm still using VS2010. Thank you for the tip.